# How do i get a sqlite database from server in ios

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm programming an iPhone app using a sqlite database. Every year, I need to update the database from a server.

Now I have two questions:

1. Should I update the database or should I overwrite the older database (The sqlite file is approximately 2MB)?
2. How would I do that?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880392/ios-update-a-core-data-db-from-json/21881435#21881435

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many data you wanna change from the old database. If just few data need to be changed, just update the DB, otherwise replace it.

Here is how to update the DB:

1. Download the script file to iPhone
2. Parse the script into an sql command list
3. Run the sql command for updates